# HTTP Basic authentication with remote Gremlin-Server

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm currently running a TitanDB cluster with gremlin-server in order to access it remotely using the exposed REST API. Currently I'm looking into how to secure the graph from malicious external access and have found that gremlin-server supports HTTP Basic authentication since 3.0.1-incubating as far as I can see. I have found a sample configuration file for running a "secure" server [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server-rest-secure.yaml) but am starting to wonder how to apply this for a normal user:password authentication. Could anyone of you lead me to some resources clarifying this or give an easy configuration example?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Tim, you can find the documentation on Gremlin Server security in the [TinkerPop3 documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_security). Out of the box, you could use the Credentials Graph DSL to maintain the authorized users. Otherwise, if you have some other means of storing credentials, such as LDAP, you can supply your own [Authenticator](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/auth/Authenticator.html) implementation which can handle the calls to your credential store.